# PHP + MySQL - What alternatives to handle (small) time series?

Tags: php, mysql, time-series, influxdb, opentsdb

I was asked to build an expense report framework which allows users to store their expenses, one at a time, via a web form. The number of entries will never be more than 100-200 per day.

In addition to the date and time, to be provided by the user, there must be a pre-defined set of tags (e.g.: transportation, lodging, food) to choose from for each new row of data, as well as fields for currency, amount and comments.

Afterwards, it must be possible (or rather, easy) to fetch the entries in the db between two dates and store the data in a pandas data frame (or R data table) for posterior statistical analysis and plotting.

I first thought about using PHP to insert the data in a mySQL database table, where the tags would be columns of booleans (True/False). The very simple web form would load by default with all tags set to False and it would be up to the user to turn the right ones to True prior to submission.

This said, I am now wondering about the other approaches I can or should explore. I've been reading about openTSDB and InfluxDB, which are designed to handle massive amounts of data, but I am also interested in hearing from coders up-to-date with the latest technologies about other possible options.

In short, I wish to choose a wise approach which is neither dated nor a (complex) cannon to kill a fly.

Comment: well, mysql *is* somewhat dated but won't disappear anytime soon. MongoDB is another possibility, but for 100-200 entries a day, I don't think you really need a overly powerful underlying database. MySQL would do the thing.

Comment: You're talking about under 100,000 entries per year, probably don't need any type of big data solution. Its really your preference, but PHP / MySQL would work well for this scenario.

Comment: then dog your data off to other tables after a while if not needed in the current active set for such data analytics

Comment: InfluxDB has a number of [assumptions and tradeoffs](https://influxdb.com/blog/2015/06/03/InfluxDB_clustering_design.html) it makes about the data in order to deliver higher throughput. I think those tradeoffs would get in the way of what you are trying to do, and as others have stated, at the write volumes you describe MySQL is perfectly performant. I strongly suspect you don't need a specialized datastore like InfluxDB.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Axibase Time-Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) Community Edition. It's free.

- Supports tags for entities, metrics, and series tags
- Provides open-source API clients for R, Python, and PHP
- Range time-series query is a core use case

Check out [App examples](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/data-applications/) you can easily build in PHP, Go, NodeJS. Application code is open source under Apache 2 license and is hosted on github.

Disclosure: I work for the Axibase.